# Detect clicks inside a Div but outside of a particular child Div in VueJS

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a page in which I have MCQ Options which looks like this:
[image: Options]

This is the HTML Code for the options parts till now:

```
<div v-for="(option, index) in optionsForFrontend">
            <div class="option">
                <div class="radio-check-item">
                    <input type="radio"
                        name="question"
                        :value="index"
                        v-model="picked"
                        v-if="question.metadata.choices === 'Single'">
                    <input type="checkbox"
                        name="question"
                        :value="index"
                        v-model="picked"
                        v-if="question.metadata.choices === 'Multiple'">
                </div>
                <div class="divider">

                </div>
                <div class="content-item">
                    <vue-markdown :source="option.option"></vue-markdown>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I want to select the options by clicking on the option content. So I put a `:click="functionToSelectOption"` on the outer div ("option") containing checkbox and option content.

The problem is when I select the checkbox, it gets selected and the function "functionToSelectOption" gets called as well since the checkbox is inside the "option" div.

I want to be able to detect a click inside the "option" div but outside radio/checkbox div so I can call the function to toggle the option.

I mostly found similar questions under jquery tags and nothing with VueJS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would avoid event.stopPropagation(). All kinds of things might be listening higher up in the tree. For instance, you might want an onclick on the window to close a modal dialog if the user clicks outside the dialog. The much less radical way to do this is to look at event.target. [This jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bbsimonbb/yt90ue5r/) tests `(event.target == event.currentTarget)` so it only reacts to clicks on the parent div.

**Markup**

```
<div id="ctr">
  <div v-for="(option,index) in options" 
    style="margin:10px;padding:10px;border:solid;border-radius:4px"
    @click="parent"
  >
    <input type="checkbox" :name="'invidiousChoice' + index" @click='child'> {{option.label}}
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var vm = new Vue({
  el:"#ctr",
  data : {
  options:[{label:'terrible option'},{label:'disastorous option'}]
  },
  methods: {
    parent: function(event) {
      if(event.target == event.currentTarget)
        alert( 'parent clicked');
    }
  }  
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use event.stopPropagation() in child element.

Here is working JSFiddle Solution: [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/5sLtK/11/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="app">
<div @click="parent">
    Parent
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" @click="child">
    </div>
</div>
{{message}}
```

**JS**

```
new Vue({
el: '#app',
data: {
    message: ''   
},
methods: {
     parent: function() {
        this.message = 'parent clicked';
    },
    child: function() {
        event.stopPropagation()
    }
}
});
```

Comment: Your link is not working. It shows parent clicked when I click child.

Comment: Works finally. Thankyou!